# Image will not be displayed after editing the values with wt-forms in Flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I am new to Python/Flask.Here is my problem is, i did't use wt-forms for posting values to server.but, i am using wt-forms for editing the values.fortunately it's working.but problem is photo will not be displayed after editing the values.when i add the image in browser inspect elements that photo will be showed. it might be problem in template. can anyone help me.thanks for advanced.

Here is the Template Code driver_edit.html

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>name: </label>
    <input name="name" type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="enter name">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>photo: </label>
    <input name="photo" type="file"  class="form-control" placeholder="upload photo">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Aadhar: </label>
    <input name="aadhar" type="file"  class="form-control" placeholder="up_load photo">
</div>
```

Here is the view.html code.

```
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>
        name
     </th>
     <th>
        photo
     </th>
    <th>
        aadhar
    </th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
{% for values in driver   %}
<tr>
 <td>{{values.name}}</td>
 <td>{{values.id}}</td>  **here it is working {{values.id}}**
 <td><a href="assets/images/{{values.photo}}"><img src="assets/images/{{values.photo}}" height="40" width="30"/></a>{{values.photo}}</td>
 <td><a href="assets/images/{{values.aadhar}}"><img src="assets/images/{{values.aadhar}}" width="30" height="40" width="30"/></a>{{values.photo}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Here is the Python code for posting values to database from web interface.

```
def driver(request):  
   file2=request.files['photo']
   file3=request.files['aadhar']
   if  file2.filename and file3.filename == None:
       flash('No selected file')
       return redirect(request.url)
   filename=''
   if file2:
    filename = secure_filename(file2.filename)
    file2.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], file2.filename))
   if file3:
    filename = secure_filename(file3.filename)
    file3.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], file3.filename))

 newdriver=Driver(name=request.form['name'],photo=file2.filename,aadhar=file3.filename,
 status=request.form['status'],lastlogin=request.form['lastlogin'])

 sqlsession.add(newdriver)
 sqlsession.commit()

@app.route('/static/driver')
def driversearch():
   if session['username']:
    return render_template('driversearching.html',user=session['username'],Truck_company=get_truckdetails().all())
   else:
      flash('login first')
      return main()

@app.route('/static/driverdetails')
def driverdetails():
    if session['username']:
       users=getdriver()
       if users.first()==None:
          return render_template('empty.html',user=session['username'])
       else:
          return render_template('driverdetails.html',user=session['username'],driver=users.all())
```

Here is the wtf forms code.py:

```
class DriverForm(FlaskForm):
    name=StringField('name')
    photo=StringField('photo')
    aadhar=StringField('aadhar')

@app.route('/newoneedit')
def newoneedit():
   form=DriverForm()
   if form.validate_on_submit():
     details={

        'photo':'form.photo.data',
        'aadhar':'form.aadhar.data',

    }
    sqlsession.add(details)
    return redirect(url_for('driverdetails'))
return render_template('driver_edit.html',form=form)

@app.route('/control/editdriver/<int:id>',methods=['GET','POST'])
def edituser(id):
   qry=sqlsession.query(Driver).filter(Driver.id==id).first()
   form=DriverForm(request.form,obj=qry)
   if request.method=='POST' or 'GET' and form.validate_on_submit():
       form.populate_obj(qry)
       sqlsession.add(qry)
       sqlsession.commit()
       return redirect(url_for('driverdetails'))
   return render_template('driver_edit.html',form=form,car_id=id,Truck_company=get_truckdetails().all(),driver=driver)
```

Here is the Database Model class:

```
class Driver(Base):
  __tablename__=='driver'
    name=Column(String(100))
    photo= Column(String(100),nullable=True)
    aadhar=Column(String(50),nullable=True)
```

Here I'am using the stringfield in wt forms for photos and for database I'am using string.

Comment: Not enough info here-- you mention `view.html` but there's no mention of that in your Flask code, and within that code you mention `{{values.photo}}` but I can't see where values is passed to any template.

Comment: @Doobeh.. i just modified the view.html

Comment: You've added `driver=driver` to the template rendering code-- but driver is never set in the routes code-- so the code would unlikely run at all.  I'm guessing it should be `driver=qry`.  If that was the case, in your `view.html` template code, which again, is never rendered by the code you posted, you wouldn't have to iterate over it-- just `{{ driver.photo}}` and `{{ driver.aadhar }}` should work, since `qry` is a single instance of a `Driver` model.

Comment: but, posting method is working and images also we able to see.

Comment: only the problem is ,while editing the details that images unable to see.

Comment: From your updated code you say `**here it is working {{values.id}}**`.  But how? `{{values.id}}` shouldn't work, because your `Driver` model doesn't have an `id`, and in your model you have `__tablename__ == 'driver'` which should be a single `=`.  Sorry, there's just not enough to go on for me to assist.

Comment: __tablename__='driver' it 's ok. i tried many times it's working well.but after editing the photo it's not visible.

Comment: No need to update title to state that you updated the question. Also, no need for "Please help" – not in your question and *especially* not in your title. (Coz if we allow that everyone would name his question the same.)